# What restrictions are there on the appearance of glamoured studded leather armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, armor, illusion

I was wondering about the glamoured aspect of [*glamoured studded leather*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/glamoured-studded-leather) armor. The description states that:

> You can also use a bonus action to speak the armor's command word and cause the armor to assume the appearance of a normal set of clothing or some other kind of armor. You decide what it looks like, including color, style, and accessories, but the armor retains its normal bulk and weight. The illusory appearance lasts until you use this property again or remove the armor.

What are the restrictions on the appearance it can take? For instance, can I make it look like full plate armor, helmet and everything? I know leather armor can include a leather cap, but a leather cap does not cover the face like a full helmet does in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is an illusion, so you're going to have to ask your GM. Here is how I personally understand/rule the armor

The Glamour Studded Leather Armor states:

> You can also use a bonus action to speak the armor's command word and **cause the armor to assume the appearance of a normal set of clothing or some other kind of armor**. You decide what it looks like, including color, style, and accessories, but the armor retains its normal bulk and weight.

I would compare this with the [*disguise self*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disguise-self) spell which states:

> You make yourself, including your clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person, look different until the spell ends or until you use your action to dismiss it. [...]

I would say the *disguise self* spell *does* allow any armor created to move as it normally would, otherwise there'd be nearly no reason to change your appearance as the illusion would be seen through near-instantly.

Similarly with the Glamour Armor, if it did not move and act like the replicated armor then the illusion would be seen through near-instantly. The armor even gives the example of turning the leather armor into normal clothing which moves nothing similar to leather armor. Thus I believe that any armor you replicate will appear as it normally would on a creature.

---

The armor "assumes the appearance" of clothing/armor, it does not actually change its shape or size, only how it appears. This means that its physical form is not being altered so physical interactions with the armor would reveal it to be an illusion.

The only things that remain the same are the bulk and weight of the *original* armor, that is, the character using the armor will not feel a change in it when they alter it, and there will not be changes to strength requirements or stealth disadvantages.

Comment: If it retains it's bulk and you make it look like plate, that seems like it's going to be very different looking plate. *Disguise self* also states "For example, if you use this spell to add a hat to your outfit, objects pass through the hat, and anyone who touches it would feel nothing or would feel your head and hair. If you use this spell to appear thinner than you are, the hand of someone who reaches out to touch you would bump into you while it was seemingly still in midair." The Glamour does not give that option.

Comment: That's not an unreasonable ruling. But I think that's what it is: a ruling. Illusions almost always require DM adjudication unless it is explicit - and it's not explicit when you have to come up with a logic train.

Comment: @NautArch Hopefully edited to clarify now, removing my comments now

Comment: I don't understand what you ruling is here, are you saying it looks and acts as whatever you want it to look like?

Comment: @SeriousBri That's what I would rule, it looks and acts like an armor/clothing of your choice, otherwise it's near-instantaneously found out (armor that doesn't move at all is *highly* suspicious), just like *disguise self*

Comment: Hol up - it also acts (functionally and mechanically) like the illusion?

Comment: @NautArch The illusion does not gain any new *mechanical interactions* however it does *look and move* exactly how it should, otherwise the armor changing is nearly useless. Leather armor that merely *looks* like clothing will be seen through *immediately* by anybody

Answer (score -1):

## Talk with your DM

[Glamoured Studded Leather](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/glamoured-studded-leather) (DMG, 172) states:

> You can also use a bonus action to speak the armor's command word and cause the armor to assume the appearance of a normal set of clothing or some other kind of armor. You decide what it looks like, including color, style, and accessories, but the armor retains its normal bulk and weight. The illusory appearance lasts until you use this property again or remove the armor.

The language gives you some freedom to assume "some other kind of armor" and even lets you explicitly turn it into a "normal set of clothing" - but it also states that it retains its normal bulk and weight. The specific aspects is allows is control over:

- color
- style
- accessories

What that means is going to be up for discussion, but as long as the armor you're emulating is similar in bulk and weight, you've got a lot of freedom in it's illusory appearance.

It remains up to your DM to determine what is reasonable and how certain options may appear. For instance, making it look like Plate may result in visual incongruity of plate mail moving or draping like studded leather over your body.

Comment: I have seen many discussions saying to make it look like noble finery but based on your answer that wouldn't be acceptable. If it is restricted to similar bulk then it would not be able to look like things like cloaks or boots. I guess that will limit my uses. Hmm

Comment: @NautArch That very much depends on what group you are playing with.  Some groups interepret that as 'you still have or don't have disadvantage on Stealth checks and you still need or do not need a certain STR score'.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer And that's why I said talk to your DM